# reading from file to structure writes only the first structure in the array

Tags: c

I am trying to get data into my structure, now when I do it only gets the first row of the file into the structure.

I assume that i don't know how many names i have in the file.

```
int InputData(student ** p_array, FILE * fp) {
    student * arr;
    int i = 1;`

    if (!(arr = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student)))) {
        printf("no");
        _getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %d", arr[i - 1].name, &arr[i - 1].grades[0], &arr[i - 1].grades[1], &arr[i - 1].grades[2]) != EOF) {
        i++;
        if (!(arr = (student*)realloc(arr, i*sizeof(student))))
        {printf("no"); _getch(); exit(1); }
    }
    arr = (student*)realloc(arr, (i - 1) * sizeof(student));
    *p_array = arr;
    if (i = 1)
        return (i);       /*return the number of students*/
    else
        return (i - 1);
}
```

a example for the file content

```
 Moshe 100 80 90
 Dana 56 89 78
 Maya 88 87 91
 Adam 90 74 81
```

the array only gets this row

```
 Moshe 100 80 90
```

please help me to fix the code.

Comment: The statement `if (i = 1)` looks fishy, did you mean `if (i == 1)`? These mistakes are difficult to track, so it suggested to follow good coding practices like `if(1 == i)`

Comment: hahah thanks but dident solve the actual problem

Comment: You need to read (and discard) the end-of-line characters at the end of the lines in the file. you can do this by including at least one whitespace character at the end of scanf's format specifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work better if you simplify the code a bit:

```c
int InputData(student **p_array, FILE *fp)
{
    student *arr;
    char buf[80];
    int i = 0;

    arr = (student *)malloc(sizeof(student));
    if (!arr) {
        printf("no");
        _getch();
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %d", arr[i].name, &arr[i].grades[0], &arr[i].grades[1], &arr[i].grades[2]) != EOF) {
        i++;
        arr = (student *)realloc(arr, (i + 1) * sizeof(student));
        if (!arr)
            err(errno, "Failed realloc() array");
    }

    arr = (student *)realloc(arr, i * sizeof(student));
    *p_array = arr;

    return i;       /* return number of students */
}
```